# Correct Validation of an inputbox via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Javascript I'm trying to validate the user's input.
Is there a way i can show ( define the text via *.html()* ) the (upper) closest element with classname "xy"

my HTML-File looks like this:

```
  <div class=" row validate" style="display:none;">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div> 
        <div class="col-lg-7"><p class="validation_text"></p></div>   
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-12"></div> 
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a href="#" data-
     toggle="tooltip" data-placement=" auto top" title="Text">Information</a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><input id="xy" name="xy" 
  type="search" class="form-control"  maxlength="2" onChange="validate(this);">
  </div>
</div>
```

and in My JS-File:

```
 function validate(){
 var regex = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?()]/);
 var box = ['xy','xyyy];
    var element;

element = document.getElementById(box[i]);

 for (i=0; i < box.length; i++){

  if(regex.test(element.value)){
        $(element).parent().parent().prev().show();
        element.style.border = '2px solid red';
$(".validation_text").eq([i]).html("your input contains regex");
 } 
 }
    }
```

everything works fine, the only problem i've got is the last part. the validation_text is not showing. Does anybody know why?

Comment: `.eq([i]).` why the brackets?

Comment: Have you checked line `var box = ['xy','xyyy];`? Is the missing ' a typo or a forgotten one?

Comment: Am I reading your `eq` correctly? You're saying "give me the element with class 'validation_text' whose index is a new array of `i`"?

Answer (score 5):

eq() expects an integer and you are giving it an array

```
$(".validation_text").eq([i])
```

should be

```
$(".validation_text").eq(i)
```